# VMWare Fusion guest application list

Tags: windows-xp, mac, virtualization, vmware-fusion

How does VMWare Fusion compile its list of guest OS applications (specifically for Windows) that can be found by "show package contents" of

```
USER/Documents/Virtual Machines/VMNAME
```

and then in the resulting window navigating to the "Applications" directory? I would like to be able to add something to this list and I just want to know where in my Windows guest OS I need to put it in order to show up in this list.

Comment: I'm having this problem on vmware fusion 4.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of bundles is not a Fusion related item at all but a way that Mac OS X has allowed developers to group their data together for a long time. It allows to cut down on various versions of files being scattered all over the hard drive.

In fact, if you head to /Applications, you'll be able to do the same thing : right-click, Show package contents, and you can see how an application is 'bundled' as well.

Bundles are a well-used feature of Mac OS X. Developers can choose to register a file extension, for example ".vmwarevm", to be a bundle and act as a single file instead of a folder of files. I imagine the thinking is that developers can choose to hide some of the complexity of applications by packing up a handful of files into a single unit. Mac OS X applications, among many other things, are also bundles. It should be noted that other OSes don't understand bundles, and simply see a folder full of files, so it's not the sort of thing you can use in Windows.

See [Bundle programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: The vmware allows some of its applications to be viewed as an mac application from outside. It will run using vmware but I can access it from the applications menus and via some scripting. But the program that I want is not in the list of windows programs that allow me to do that.

Comment: You could use [vmrun](http://blogs.vmware.com/vix/2008/12/managing-vm-guests-using-vmrun.html) to execute applications on the guest that are not in the list. More info in [this pdf](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vix180_vmrun_command.pdf).